How to go about setting up Cloudwatch logs for internsl server errors for NestJs running on an EC2 instance
Our backend application is built with NestJs, it's deployed on an EC2 instance and only logs to the console. We've been having issues lately with db transaction timeouts and internal server errors that are hard to track down. I'm new to working with logging. I would like to be able to setup logging and Cloudwatch for our server so it will not take as long to track down issues, but am not sure how to go about this. I've seen tuts for system logging, which isn't what I'm looking for. I'm assuming I would have to have our server log to a file and then send that log over to cloudwatch via the cloudwatch agent? Will that catch internal  server errors?
